# Как применить css свойство к изображениям внутри iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

В сниппете ниже проблема в том, что к изображению, которое находится в iframe применяется класс `message--dark`, но при этом не применяется свойство `.message--dark img` и видно большую разницу между изображениями. Это можно как то исправить?

```js
function changeTheme() {
  let toggle = document.getElementById('dn');
  toggle.onclick = function() {
    changeClass();
  };
}

function changeClass() {
  const body = document.querySelector('body');
  if (!body.classList.contains('message--dark')) {
    body.classList.add('message--dark')
  } else {
    body.classList.remove('message--dark')
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', changeTheme);
```

```css
.message--dark {
  filter: invert(0.8) hue-rotate(180deg);
  /* hue-rotate возвращает тона обратно */
}

.message--dark img,
iframe img {
  filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg) !important;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

img,
iframe {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="dn">
<label for="dn">Press me</label>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559500785-15520313cfe2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1103&q=80" alt="">
  <iframe src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559500785-15520313cfe2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1103&q=80" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Этот сниппет на codepen: https://codepen.io/Clasen00/pen/zQbJxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил классу .container, класс с этим св-вом:

```css
.message--dark { 
  /* hue-rotate возвращает тона обратно */ 
  filter: invert(0.8) hue-rotate(180deg);
}
```

**Codepen**: 
https://codepen.io/Clasen00/pen/zQbJxy